# Play-Framework: Cannot parse parameter companyId as BSONObjectID: wrong ObjectId

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am using play-framework with Reactive mongo drivers. For handling reactive mongo `BSONObjectId` in our routes file, i am creating following binders:

```
object StringToBSONObjectIdBinder {

 /* This is for Path Parameter*/

 implicit object pathBindableBSONObjectID extends play.api.mvc.PathBindable.Parsing[BSONObjectID](
  BSONObjectID(_), _.stringify,
  (key: String, e: Exception) =>
   "Cannot parse parameter %s as BSONObjectID: %s".format(key, e.getMessage))

 /* This is for query String*/

 implicit object queryStringBindableBSONObjectID extends play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable.Parsing[BSONObjectID](
  BSONObjectID(_), _.stringify,
  (key: String, e: Exception) =>
   "Cannot parse parameter %s as BSONObjectID: %s".format(key, e.getMessage))
}
```

In routing i am easily route my id as a path param like following example:

```
GET      /company/:companyId/users-detail       controllers.CompanyController.userDetail(companyId: BSONObjectID)
```

My `BSONObjectId` easily mapped with my request handler path param. But when i am using following route after above route as below:

```
GET /company/detail        controllers.CompanyController.companyDetail
```

I am getting following `BadRequest`:

```
    For request 'GET /company/detail?t=1466673779753' [Cannot parse parameter companyId as BSONObjectID: wrong ObjectId: &#x27;teams&#x27;]
```

But when i switch the routes as below:

```
GET /company/detail        controllers.CompanyController.companyDetail
GET      /company/:companyId/users-detail       controllers.CompanyController.userDetail(companyId: BSONObjectID)
```

Services run successfully. I am still no getting what actual problem is. This is play-framework issue, or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

First you re-implement a `QueryBindable`, whereas the BSON one is already provided by the Play plugin: [see sample](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/master/src/test/scala/PathBindableSpec.scala)

Then you pass the value `"teams"`, which is not a valid representation for `BSONObjectID`.